# laravel ->count() vs ->get()->count()

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Why are the two statement below behaving differentlY? The first returns 3 the second returns 1 for $progress. I thought that the first aggregates on the DB and the second on the server. So they should still return the same value.

```
$progress = $this->user->userActivities()->select('date')
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->get()->count();

$progress =  $this->user->userActivities()->select('date')
                ->groupBy('date')
                ->count();
```

Comment: It's the opposite, the first is counting the collection in PHP and the second is counting the rows in the DB.  However, I've never seen a case that they would return differently,  the second is definitely going to be more efficient.  What does get() actually return?

Answer (score 35):

`->get()->count()` will load Eloquent model objects into memory and then will count those.

`->count()` will use DB aggregate function, so it will definitely be more efficient:

```
select count(*) as aggregate ...
```

Answer (score 10):

It's quite late answer but I had faced the same issue. These two examples are returning two different counts because of **groupBy** you have used.

```
$progress = $this->user->userActivities()->select('date')
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->get()->count();
```

This takes the rows first, then count the row numbers and returns the count.

```
$progress =  $this->user->userActivities()->select('date')
            ->groupBy('date')
            ->count();
```

Whereas this counts the rows by its group in the DB and returns the first group's row record count only from the list.

the solution I used instead of **get()->count()** for my case is like

```
$progress =  $this->user->userActivities()
            ->distinct('date')
            ->count('date');
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `->get()->count()` is wrong. I used `->get()->count()` in my web app and when my database records have more than 80000 records I get error 500 in my app.

Comment: So what is the solution? You should add an alternative solution

Answer (score 2):

The first counts the number of returned records, the second counts the records and returns the number. If you are using a paging of 10, for example, then the first will yield 10 and the second the actual number if the number of mathcing elements is greater than 10.

Answer (score 0):

```php
$count = Model::all()->count();
return view('home',compact('count'));
```

this will function for laravel 6;

Comment: Extremely inefficient, imagine what will happen when your DB has more than 1M records

Answer (score -3):

Both of them return the same result. But as said for preventing to crash or decrease the speed of response it's better to use `count()` instead of `get()->count()`

Comment: Not the same, one ->count() gets database count (COUNT) and ->get()->count() returns collection count. Most of the time they return the same number, but functionally they are not the same.